# How can I use Thomson Reuters Eikon to get a list of large historical companies?

Tags: market-data, market, reuters

I am trying to use Thomson Reuters Eikon to get a list of historically large companies, for example, what were the 1000 largest companies by market capitalization in 1990? I would like to get lists of every company from 1990 to 2015 that had a market capitalization [at any point] over $10 billion USD. I have tried using the formula builder and Eikon's research tools but cannot do this task.

Comment: Calculating historical market cap (or even today's market cap) seems like an easy metric to find.. until you start digging further.  For example, Google today consists of two listed share types and one unlisted share type, and you need to sum all three.  Do you include hybrid convertible debt instruments that may have been issued?  How do you handle other events such as mergers/spinoffs?  For companies that use tracking stocks (look at Liberty Media as an example) to track part of the company, do you combine them?  Certainly a can of worms.

Comment: Maybe an indirect (but certainly not perfect) method would be to cross check with a book/magazine released at the time. I thought at Fortune 500 list for the US but they don't seem to have the market cap. ;(